# Unsupported object type in Tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on [regression with Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression), but the code from the tutorial throws an error. Is the tutorial out of date, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code from the start of the tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make NumPy printouts easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

import tensorflow as tf


print(tf.__version__)

url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
column_names = ['MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', 'Horsepower', 'Weight',
                'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin']

raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names,
                          na_values='?', comment='\t',
                          sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

dataset = raw_dataset.copy()
dataset = dataset.dropna()
dataset['Origin'] = dataset['Origin'].map({1: 'USA', 2: 'Europe', 3: 'Japan'})
dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=['Origin'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
print(dataset.tail())
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_features = train_dataset.copy()
test_features = test_dataset.copy()

train_labels = train_features.pop('MPG')
test_labels = test_features.pop('MPG')

print(train_dataset.describe().transpose()[['mean', 'std']])
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features))
```

When I run that, the last line raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/scratches/scratch2.py", line 36, in <module>
    normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features))
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py", line 286, in adapt
    super().adapt(data, batch_size=batch_size, steps=steps)
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/base_preprocessing_layer.py", line 246, in adapt
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1260, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 246, in __init__
    x, y, sample_weights = _process_tensorlike((x, y, sample_weights))
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1140, in _process_tensorlike
    inputs = tf.nest.map_structure(_convert_single_tensor, inputs)
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 917, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 917, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1135, in _convert_single_tensor
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/don/.local/share/virtualenvs/zero-play-9HEKD3Xj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Tensorflow is picky about `int` versus `float`, so convert all the inputs to floats. Changing the last line to this solves the problem:

```
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features).astype(float))
```